# Нужна ли запятая после "а где"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

### "А где(?) не подскажешь?"

Если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представим себе разговор подружек.

— Я тоже себе такие купила.
— А где, не подскажешь?

А где [ты их купила] (что сделала?) — неполное предложение (без главных членов);
[ты] не подскажешь (что сделаешь?) — односоставное (без подлежащего).
Между двумя простыми предложениями нужна запятая.

[Неполные предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Дело в том, что сомнения появились из-за неудачного, как я уже поняла, исправления со стороны оппонента.